# Linking Boost Python on OSX 10.10

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost, cmake

I am trying to build the project from: https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples which is a set of boost python examples on Yosemite.

First I installed Boost and Boost python and cmake

```
brew install boost
brew install boost-pyton
brew install cmake
```

I've run into the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/bin/cmake -H/Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples -B/Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build/CMakeFiles /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f 01-HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make 01-HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/depend
cd /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/01-HelloWorld /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build/01-HelloWorld /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build/01-HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f 01-HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make 01-HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build
Linking CXX shared module hello.so
cd /Users/demo/devel/boost-python-examples/build/01-HelloWorld && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/hello.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -g -bundle -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   -o hello.so CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.cpp.o /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyString_Type", referenced from:
      boost::python::to_python_value<char const* const&>::get_pytype() const in hello.cpp.o
  "__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
      boost::python::api::object::object() in hello.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [01-HelloWorld/hello.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [01-HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks like its calling:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -stdlib=libstdc++ -g -bundle -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   -o hello.so CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.cpp.o /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
```

I've tried the following:

- Removing the `-stdlib=libstdc++`
- Using `gcc` instead of `c++`
- Using `-m32` (bad idea)

As far as i can tell the dynlib is good:
`/usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

So I'm not sure where my issue currently is.  I'm assuming its some sort of build flag i'm missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to link in the Python library.

In your CMakeLists.txt you can add

```
include(FindPythonLibs)
```

This will define a variable `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` which you can then use like this

```
target_link_libraries(your_exe ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to force `cmake` to use the right directories:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=xxx -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=xxx -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=xxx ..
```